# SQL delete with exists is not working in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm running this select in MariaDB and it works as expected, it's just a select with an `exists`:

```
select * from pred_loan_defaults  d
where exists (select 1 from pred_loan_defaults d2 
where d.exec_id = d2.exec_id and d.loan_identifier = d2.loan_identifier 
and d2.default_status = 1 and d.prediction_date > d2.prediction_date)
order by loan_identifier, prediction_date
```

Now, I'm trying to delete the rows that were selected, so I adjusted the statement:

```
delete from pred_loan_defaults  d
where exists (select * from pred_loan_defaults d2 
where d.exec_id = d2.exec_id and d.loan_identifier = d2.loan_identifier 
and d2.default_status = 1 and d.prediction_date > d2.prediction_date);
```

But I get an error:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=6) You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'd

What is wrong with the `delete` statement?

Comment: Are you pointing to the correct database?  Perhaps target the correct database like `use 'TestDb'` as an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use an alias after the table name in a single-table delete.

You need to use `JOIN` rather than `WHERE EXISTS`.

```
delete d
FROM pred_loan_defaults AS d
JOIN prod_loan_defaults AS d2
    ON d.exec_id = d2.exec_id 
        AND d.loan_identifier = d2.loan_identifier 
        AND d.prediction_date > d2.prediction_date
WHERE d2.default_status = 1
```